# Asking on specific Backpack fitting specific laptop?

Tags: discussion, scope

> I want to buy a specific backpack but the only thing that keeps me - I am not sure it will fit my specific laptop (which usually does not fit normal laptop sleeves).

I was wondering would such a question be ok to ask here on travel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the reaction to [Would Osprey Farpoint-40 rucksack fit (onto laptop sleeve) 17 inch laptop?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80138/would-osprey-farpoint-40-rucksack-fit-onto-laptop-sleeve-17-inch-laptop) the answers is, it was.

Comment: What If I would ask specifically about bag model (as there are quite few high end bags) but only say that it's 17'' laptop? This way it would cover broader range of laptops (and everyone carries laptop these days) - would be helpful to broader range of visitors.